# Streaming large SOAP attachments

Tags: web-services, soap

I am building a web service that returns a large "result set" as a `List<List<String>>`. As I want to avoid representing the result set in XML as part of the SOAP message, I am now adding it as an attachment and am using a simple custom encoding. The result set can be pretty large,  like hundreds of GBs. I want to avoid holding the thing in memory (hence I use an `Iterator<List<String>>` instead of a `List<List<String>>`). Also I want to be able to "pipeline" or stream the data. In particular, what I want to achieve is that the client can start processing the first results while the server has not even finished writing. Actually, I am not totally sure whether this is possible at all. In fact it is currently not happening.

This is my service implementation

```
@MTOM // enable Message Transmission Optimization Mechanism (MTOM) at the server
@WebService ( endpointInterface = "com.SnafucatorWS" )
@StreamingAttachment(parseEagerly = true, memoryThreshold = 4000000L)
public class SnafucatorWSImpl implements SnafucatorWS {
  ...
  @Override
  public GetNodesResponse getNodes() {
    Iterator<List<String>> result = impl.getNodes();    
    return new GetNodesResponse(result);
  }
}
```

How I create the client connection

```
  private SnafucatorWS connect() {
    if ( serviceUrl == null ) { 
      throw new UncheckedConnectionException("The service url of the snafucator webservice has not been set"); 
    }
    Service result = null;
    try {
      result = Service.create(
         new URL(serviceUrl + "?wsdl"),
         new QName("http://com/", "SnafucatorWSImplService") );
      } catch ( MalformedURLException e ) {
        LOG.fatal("Could not create web service endpoint.", e);
      }
      SnafucatorWS port = result.getPort(SnafucatorWS.class);
      // enable Message Transmission Optimization Mechanism (MTOM) at the client (for transmission of binary data)
      BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider)port;
      SOAPBinding soapBinding = (SOAPBinding)bindingProvider.getBinding();
      soapBinding.setMTOMEnabled(true);    
      return port;
    }
```

This is my code for the response and for encoding and decoding the data:

```
@XmlAccessorType ( XmlAccessType.NONE )
@XmlRootElement ( name = "getNodesResponse" )
@XmlType ( name = "getNodesResponseType" )
public class GetNodesResponse {
  private static final ExecutorService POOL = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
  private DataHandler results;
  private BlockingQueue<List<String>> resultSet;
  private volatile boolean hasNext;
  private final CountDownLatch streamOpened = new CountDownLatch(1);

  ...

  @XmlElement ( required = true )
  @XmlMimeType ( "*/*" )
  public DataHandler getResults() {
    return results;
  }

 void setResults(DataHandler aDataHandler) {
   results = aDataHandler;
   resultSet = new ArrayBlockingQueue<List<String>>(100);    
   StreamingDataHandler dataHandler = (StreamingDataHandler)results;
   try {
     parse(dataHandler, resultSet);
   } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   }
 }

 /**
  * @return true, if the result set serves more elements
  * @throws InterruptedException if the current thread was interrupted
  */
 public boolean hasNext() throws InterruptedException {
   streamOpened.await();
   return ( hasNext || !resultSet.isEmpty() );
 }

 /**
  * Results can be accessed by successively calling
  * {@link java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue#take()} as long as {@link #hasNext()} returns true. Please note, however,
  * that an invalid result stream may cause {@link #hasNext()} to return true erroneously, hence the queue might block indefinitely. 
  * 
  * @return the result set as a blocking queue
  */
 public BlockingQueue<List<String>> getResultSet() {
   return resultSet; 
 }

 private DataHandler encode(Iterator<List<String>> aResults) {
   assert ( aResults != null );
   final PipedOutputStream out = new PipedOutputStream();
   DataHandler dh = new DataHandler(new StreamDataSource(out, "*/*"));
   Encoder encoder = new Encoder(out, aResults);
   @SuppressWarnings("unused")
   Future<?> future = POOL.submit(encoder);
   return dh;
 }

 private void parse(StreamingDataHandler dataHandler, final Queue<List<String>> aResultSet) 
     throws InterruptedException {
   Decoder decoder = new Decoder(dataHandler, aResultSet);
   @SuppressWarnings("unused")
   Future<?> future = POOL.submit(decoder);
 }

 ...


private static final class StreamDataSource implements DataSource {
  private final String name = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
  private final InputStream in;
  private final String mimeType;

  private StreamDataSource(PipedOutputStream aOut, String aMimeType) {
    try {
      in = new PipedInputStream(aOut);
    } catch ( IOException e ) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Could not create input stream.", e);
    }
    mimeType = aMimeType;
  }

  @Override public String getName() { return name; }
  @Override public String getContentType() { return mimeType; }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   * 
   * This implementation violates the specification in that it is destructive. Only the first call will return an
   * appropriate input stream.
   */
  @Override public InputStream getInputStream() { return in; }

  @Override public OutputStream getOutputStream() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
}

/**
 * Decodes the contents of an input stream as written by the Encoder and writes
 * parsed rows to a {@link java.util.Queue}.
 */
private class Decoder implements Runnable {
  private final StreamingDataHandler dataHandler;
  private final Queue<List<String>> resultSet;

  public Decoder(StreamingDataHandler aDataHandler, Queue<List<String>> aResultSet) {
    dataHandler = aDataHandler;
    resultSet = aResultSet;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    try { 
      InputStream in = dataHandler.getInputStream();
      byte[] lenBytes = new byte[4];
      List<String> row;
      int rowLen;
      // read the first row's length
      in.read(lenBytes);
      rowLen = ByteBuffer.wrap(lenBytes).getInt();
      if ( rowLen == 0 ) { 
        hasNext = false;
        streamOpened.countDown();
      } else {
        hasNext = true;
        streamOpened.countDown(); // now the client can start processing / waiting for rows
        do {
          rowLen = ByteBuffer.wrap(lenBytes).getInt();
          if ( rowLen == 0 ) { break; }
          row = new ArrayList<String>(rowLen);       // read row length
          for ( int col = 0; col < rowLen; col++ ) { // for each column
            in.read(lenBytes);                       // read the value length
            int valLen = ByteBuffer.wrap(lenBytes).getInt();
            byte[] valBytes = new byte[valLen];      // allocate a buffer of appropriate size
            in.read(valBytes);
            row.add(new String(valBytes));
          }
          resultSet.add(row);
        } while ( in.read(lenBytes) > 0 );
        hasNext = false;
      }
    } catch ( IOException e ) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e); 
    } finally {
      hasNext = false;
      try {
        dataHandler.close();
      } catch ( IOException e ) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not close data handler.", e); 
      }
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Encodes the given result set and writes the result to an output stream. 
 */
private class Encoder implements Runnable {
  private final OutputStream out;
  private final Iterator<List<String>> iterator;

  public Encoder(OutputStream aOut, Iterator<List<String>> aResults) {
    out = aOut;
    iterator = aResults;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    try { 
      while ( iterator.hasNext() ) {
        List<String> row = iterator.next();
        out.write(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(row.size()).array());
        for ( String s : row ) {
          byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
          out.write(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(s.length()).array()); // write size of column in bytes
          out.write(bytes);                                             // write column value            
        }
      }
    } catch ( IOException e ) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Could not write data.", e); 
    } finally {
      try {
        out.close();
      } catch ( IOException e ) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not close data handler.", e); 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The web service returns a response containing exactly the expected result set. However, when I debug I see that the client can only start decoding after the service has closed the output stream. My goal is for the Decoder to start working (on the client side) while the Encoder task is still writing into the output stream on the server side.
Maybe this cannot be fixed, but I think it would be a great performance improvement.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed.
Beside some locking bugs in my code (not related to the original post) I had the wrong annotations and client configuration. This is how everything works fine:

The service interface

```
@WebService
public interface SnafucatorWS {
  @WebMethod ( operationName = "getNodes" )
  public GetNodesResponse getNodes();
}
```

The service implementation

```
@MTOM // enable Message Transmission Optimization Mechanism (MTOM) at the server
@WebService ( endpointInterface = "com.snafu.SnafucatorWS" )
@StreamingAttachment(parseEagerly = false, dir = "/tmp", memoryThreshold = 4000000L)
public class SnafucatorWSImpl implements SnafucatorWS {
  @Override public GetNodesResponse getNodes() { ... }
}
```

The connection configuration in the client

```
public final class SnafucatorWSClient implements SnafucatorWS {
  private SnafucatorWS connect() {
    Service result = null;
    try {
      result = Service.create(
        new URL(serviceUrl + "?wsdl"),
        new QName("http://snafu.com/", "SnafucatorWSImplService") );
    } catch ( MalformedURLException e ) {
      LOG.fatal("Could not create web service endpoint.", e);
    }
    // load off attachment to the file system when exceeding 4MB in size
    StreamingAttachmentFeature stf = new StreamingAttachmentFeature("/tmp", false, 4000000L);
    SnafucatorWS port = result.getPort(SnafucatorWS.class, new MTOMFeature(), stf);
    // enable Message Transmission Optimization Mechanism (MTOM) at the client (for transmission of binary data)
    BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider)port;
    SOAPBinding soapBinding = (SOAPBinding)bindingProvider.getBinding();
    soapBinding.setMTOMEnabled(true);
    return port;
  }
}
```

The result type

```
@StreamingAttachment(parseEagerly=false, memoryThreshold=40000L)
@XmlAccessorType ( XmlAccessType.NONE )
@XmlRootElement ( name = "getNodesResponse" )
@XmlType ( name = "getNodesResponseType" )
public class GetNodesResponse {
  @XmlElement ( required = true )
  @XmlMimeType("application/octet-stream")
  DataHandler getResults() {
    return results;
  }

  void setResults(DataHandler aDataHandler) { ... /* do the parallel parsing here */ }
}
```

Now, the client parses results before the server has closed the stream.

Comment: I implemented a little DataHandler that does the same for streams of arbitrary protocol buffers: https://bintray.com/avidd/maven/StreamingService/view/read